# Why doesn't TreeSet.contains() work?

Tags: java, classcastexception, treeset

```
public class Empty {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        TreeSet<Class> classes = new TreeSet<Class>();
        classes.add( String.class );

        String test = new String();

        try{ 
            if( classes.contains(test.getClass()) ){
                System.out.println( "contains" );
            }
        }catch(ClassCastException cce){

            System.out.println( "Expected:  "  + classes );
            System.out.println( "But it was: " + test.getClass() );
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this throw a `ClassCastException`?

Comment: the Exception should have more information what went wrong... it's almost always a good idea to print the Exception and the stack trace (just add `cce.printStackTrace()` inside the catch block)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When instantiating `TreeSet` without an explicit comparator, it expects inserted elements to implement `Comparable`, but `Class` does not implement this interface.

To fix, create a comparator for `Class`:

```
Comparator<Class> classComp = new Comparator<Class>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Class o1, Class o2)
    {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
};
TreeSet<Class> classes = new TreeSet<Class>(classComp);
```

Comment: +1 for giving the comparator, although I'd have used compareToIgnoreCase() ;-)

Comment: @candrian - Thanks for the vote. but how come you would ignore case? Class names are not case-insensitive in java, and the name (as given in the source) is what is stored inside the classfile.

Answer (score 3):

`TreeSet` is an ordered set, so any element you insert must implement `Comparable` (unless you specify a custom `Comparator`).  `Class` does not.

If you don't need the ordering, you can always use an unordered set such as [HashSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).  Otherwise, you'll need to come up with an ordering of your own.

From the Javadoc (emphasis mine):

> A NavigableSet implementation based on
>   a TreeMap. **The elements are ordered
>   using their natural ordering, or by a
>   Comparator provided at set creation
>   time**, depending on which constructor
>   is used.
>
> This implementation provides
>   guaranteed log(n) time cost for the
>   basic operations (add, remove and
>   contains).
>
> Note that **the ordering maintained by a
>   set (whether or not an explicit
>   comparator is provided) must be
>   consistent with equals** if it is to
>   correctly implement the Set interface.
>   (See Comparable or Comparator for a
>   precise definition of consistent with
>   equals.) This is so because the Set
>   interface is defined in terms of the
>   equals operation, but a TreeSet
>   instance performs all element
>   comparisons using its compareTo (or
>   compare) method, so two elements that
>   are deemed equal by this method are,
>   from the standpoint of the set, equal.
>   The behavior of a set is well-defined
>   even if its ordering is inconsistent
>   with equals; it just fails to obey the
>   general contract of the Set interface.

See also: [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote
>   Why does this throw a ClassCastException?

It was cause by the implementation of TreeMap, the TreeSet that is a key set of TreeMap is based on it.

java.lang.Class does not implement the java.lang.Comparable interface,thus it will throw an exception of ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error is `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`
. Here it is - TreeSet imposes an ordering on the elements. If you use a HashSet, all is OK.