# Phone book programming - TreeSet or HashSet

Tags: java, equals, treeset

I have a nice problem - **create a phone book** - containing list of contacts.
As a phonebook goes,

1. Contacts are to be always sorted.(by name)
2. Can star mark certain
   contacts, so they have to be above all the rest.(the * contacts
   are ordered by the time of contact creation)

   ```
   class PhoneBook{
   //require an always sorted d.s
   TreeSet<Contact> contacts = new TreeSet<Contact>();

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "PhoneBook [contacts=" + contacts + "]";
   }

   public boolean addContact(Contact contact){
       //validate before adding the contact.
       return contacts.add(contact);
   }
   ```

   }

   ```
   class Contact implements Comparable<Contact>{
   String name;
   int phoneNo;
   Date timeAdded;
   boolean starContact;



   public Contact(String name, int phoneNo, Date timeAdded, boolean starContact) {
       super();
       this.name = name;
       this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
       this.timeAdded = timeAdded;
       this.starContact = starContact;
   }



   @Override
   public int compareTo(Contact otherContact) {
       if(this.starContact && otherContact.starContact){
           return this.timeAdded.before(otherContact.timeAdded)?-1:1; //impossible to add 2 contacts at the same time
       }else if(this.starContact){
           return -1;
       }else if(otherContact.starContact){
           return 1;
       }else{
           //simple Contacts
           return this.name.compareTo(otherContact.name);
       }
   }






   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "\nContact [name=" + name + ", timeAdded=" + timeAdded
               + ", starContact=" + starContact + "]";
   }


   }
   ```

**Test Code**

```
    public class MobilePhoneBookDemo {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    PhoneBook phoneBook = new PhoneBook();

    Contact frnd1 = new Contact("Z",56,new Date(),false);
    phoneBook.addContact(frnd1);
    Contact frnd2 = new Contact("A",3,new Date(),false);
    phoneBook.addContact(frnd2);
    Contact frnd3 = new Contact("C",30,new Date(),false);
    phoneBook.addContact(frnd3);
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Contact ta = new Contact("Ta", 5, new Date(), true);
    phoneBook.addContact(ta);
    Contact ma = new Contact("Ma", 31, new Date(), true);
    phoneBook.addContact(ma);
    Contact baba = new Contact("Baba", 300, new Date(), true);
    phoneBook.addContact(baba);

    //change the priority later for one of my friends.
    System.out.println(phoneBook);
    frnd1.starContact = true;
    System.out.println(phoneBook.contacts.contains(frnd1));

    if(phoneBook.contacts.remove(frnd1)){
        System.out.println("removed");
        phoneBook.contacts.add(frnd1);
    }

    System.out.println(phoneBook);
}
```

}

Problems faced:

1. The contains doesn't find the entry anymore, what's amiss?
   I did try and put an equals and a hashcode on Contact, apparently, if there is a Comparator/Comparable present, the compare* is only invoked.
2. Is it fair to use a TreeSet here, or should any other datastructure be used?
   For eg. HashSet and then convert to a TreeSet?
3. The contains() doesn't even compare for all entries in the map, it just compared against C,Ma and Ta entries. Why was that?

Questions  priority according to order.
I appreciate all the answers, but this is indeed a complete test case, so please try and run PhoneBook just once before providing an answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If contacts must be always sorted, use a Treeset

Comment: TreeMap<Contact,?> or TreeMap<?,Contact>.If its the former, then its internally done by the TreeSet, if its the latter, then, how does it help?

Comment: It was in response to the earlier comment, where it was mentioned to use a TreeMap, however, it is now changed to a TreeSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple, first remove, then change the value and add it back again.
I comment the modification first,I have also put in the modified compareTo() since there were lots of confusion around it.

```
//frnd1.starContact = true;
    System.out.println("Entry present>"+phoneBook.contacts.contains(frnd1));

    if(phoneBook.contacts.remove(frnd1)){
        System.out.println("removed");
        frnd1.starContact = true;
        phoneBook.contacts.add(frnd1);
    }


@Override
public int compareTo(Contact otherContact) {
    if(otherContact.phoneNo == this.phoneNo){
        return 0;
    }
    if(this.starContact && otherContact.starContact){
        return this.timeAdded.before(otherContact.timeAdded)?-1:1; //impossible to add 2 contacts at the same time
    }else if(this.starContact){
        return -1;
    }else if(otherContact.starContact){
        return 1;
    }else{
        //simple Contacts
        return this.name.compareTo(otherContact.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This line:

`return this.timeAdded.before(otherContact.timeAdded)?-1:1;`

will never return 0 if you compare a contact with itself. Therefore the set will not be able to find the object with `contains()`

Comment: Really? So compareTo() will compare to itself? I almost repped this answer without testing, as it looks so good, but it actually doesn't work. The contain() never invoked compareTo() with itself.

Comment: oh downvoter,care to explain? I think SO should mandate all downvoters to atleast leave a comment, so that the downvoter owns responsibility.

Comment: Looking at the code of `TreeMap.getKey()` (where `TreeSet.contains()` ends up) it uses the comparator to find the object you are looking for. So if the set contains `frnd1`, the call to `set.contains(frnd1)` will return the object that gives 0 for the 'compareTo()'. Which in this case will be none of the entries, thus returns `null`

Comment: @anirbanchowdhury You are mistaken. It invokes compareTo() to binary-search the tree until it returns zero when comparing the search key to the entry keys.

Comment: @EJP , yes my mistake, the compareTo() may compare it to itself, but NOT always, if u doubt me, do debug once just to check it.However, this doesn't solve the question.

Answer (score 1):

You had me at

> contacts are to be always sorted.(by name)

If order is important use TreeSet. Elements are stored in a variety of binary search tree, this means that they are sorted by default.

HashSet on the other hand, does not guarantee any order, sorting or even insert order.

---

Edit - Try to write your conditions in this way, more readable and more robust as well. The order of conditions is the order of priority of comparison.

```
if(a != b){
    return a<b;
}

if(c != d) {
    return c<d;
}

//and so on.

return 0;
```

Comment: @anirbanchowdhury could you point to the reference which says `equals` wont work? "if there is a Comparator/Comparable present, the compare* is only invoked."

Comment: Do check out the contains() on the TreeSet and where it leads to. Would lead to getEntry() on the TreeMap.

Comment: [You are right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501997/why-doesnt-treeset-contains-work) In which case, the problem pointed out by Anras Kerekes is very valid, but perhaps not the whole story.

Comment: @anirbanchowdhury "The contains() doesn't even compare for all entries in the map," How do you infer that.

Comment: @anirbanchowdhury Infact the problem suggested by Anras is probably the main one, since frnd1 is a star contact.

Comment: @anirbanchowdhury and depending on the granularity of Date, it is probably easy to create 2 Contacts with same name

Comment: 1. I debugged 2. No its not, reasons mentioned in comments to his answer. It looks good, but its actually not. 3. Frankly, this was just a POC to think of a solution.I agree to your point, but doesn't answer my questions.

Comment: @anirbanchowdhury Im sorry but I need to leave for home now, Ill try to get back to you once I get there.